# Push data to client without using CallBack in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Is it possible to push data to client in WCF service without using callback?

Scenario:

There are 2 client consuming service.
Client 1 send message and then Client 2 get message send by Client 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches to this problem

1. Use
   [Publish-Subscribe Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S6)
2. Using Duplexing service in WCF

Also have a look at this article,
**Push Data to the Client using WCF CallBack Service**
 http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=721

Comment: thanx furqan..but honestly i still confuse with publish-subscribe framework..by the way thanx for giving me direction